# How to define a class that handles implicit conversion to bool when it uses a string variable in its constructor?

Tags: c#, database, caching, parameters, implicit-conversion

I have defined a class that caches the value from the database and added implicit conversions so it works as a boolean variable. 
(This class is used to get/set user preferences in our projects)

```
 public class BoolParameter
{

    private static string _ParameterName;
    private static bool? _CurrentVal;

    public BoolParameter(string ParameterName)
    {
        _ParameterName = ParameterName;
    }

    public bool Val
    {
        get
        {
            return
                (bool)
                    (_CurrentVal ??
                     (_CurrentVal =
                         DataBaseAccesor[_ParameterName] == "Y"));
        }
        set
        {
            _CurrentVal = value;
            DataBaseAccesor[_ParameterName] = value ? "Y" : "N";
        }
    }

    //setter doesnt work, how to define the implicit operator setter without passing the parametername?
   /* static public implicit operator BoolParameter(bool value)
    {
        //being a new BoolParameter it would need parametername
        return new BoolParameter(value); 
    }*/

    //getter works fine
    static public implicit operator bool(BoolParameter parameter)
    {
        return parameter.Val;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
BoolParameter parshowmessageafterupdate=new BoolParameter("UserParShowMessageAfterUpdate");

//later use
if(parshowmessageafterupdate)
{
 //show message x
}

//or later in Options Screen set the preference
//this part is what doesnt work
//parshowinitialmessage=true;

//i would have to do this instead:
parshowinitialmessage.Val=true;
```

How to define the implicit operator setter without passing the parametername?
Would this cache class be optimum vs accessing the database directly each time you read/get the parameter?

Comment: If you do an implicit conversion from `bool` to `BoolParameter` you would need to create a new object based only on the `bool` value and any other parameters would have to be defaulted.  If all you want to do is set the `Val` parameter of an existing object then you already know how to do that.  Also technically your cast from `BoolParameter` to `bool` should be explicit since it represents a lost of data (specifically the parameter name).

Comment: `BoolParameter` doesn't looks as a good idea in given scenario, what you want instead is to have some sort of manager, which handlers value conversion (has a set of methods: `AsBool`, `AsInt`, `SetBool` etc. with indexer, where key is a `string` parameter name). Usage would be `Manager.Instance["UserParShowMessageAfterUpdate"].AsBool()` and `Manager.Instance["..."].SetBool(true)`.

Comment: Aren't you delude yourself?
At the end of the day your goal is to write a value to a particular paramer to your db. How can it be done without knowing the parameter Name?
Second. I see a bug in your code. Your {get} instruction may return two different results for two individual BoolParameter objects.  what is _CurrentVal ? Is it static?

Comment: @YaugenVlasau The idea of this technique is that you would read the variable value a lot while seldom modifing it. So you want to cache the value in this case in _CurrentVal and only get it from the database the first time. And you are right  _CurrentVal and _ParameterName wouldnt be static...thats a typo i made when posting the question :/

Comment: @juharr @ sinatr It can be done directly with a manager (the DataBaseAccesor described in the code is a manager of sorts) , but i wanted to encapsullate all this logic in a class so it can be used/mantained easily (like it was a bool variable with some extra mojo) by me and other colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

Why the nullable bool?

Couldn't you use:

```
public class BoolParameter
{

    private static string _ParameterName = String.Empty;
    private static bool _CurrentVal = false;

    public BoolParameter(string ParameterName)
    {
        _ParameterName = ParameterName;
    }

    public bool Val
    {
        get
        {
            return DataBaseAccesor[_ParameterName].Equals("Y").Equals(_CurrentVal);
        }
        set
        {
            _CurrentVal = value;
            DataBaseAccesor[_ParameterName] = value ? "Y" : "N";
        }
    }
```

Comment: The nullable bool is used to check if the boolean variable is not yet initialized (first time access to the variable) so in that case i have to get the true/false value from the Database, otherwise bool types are initialized to false by default in c#